# escaping from double quote string

Tags: c#, gembox-spreadsheet

I have string `"my string"` taken from excel value, I used GemBox.Spreadsheet library. But the result I have `"""my string"""`. How to get back my real string value as `"my string`

Thanks

Comment: Check this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xU15IJ

Comment: have you tried the `string.Replace` method can you show us what you have tried vs you telling us what other people have posted doesn't work..

Comment: @MethodMan I already tried with `string.Replace` does not match what I expected. And you can see my own answer below, the result from convert file is same as what I got on my script. once again thanks for all participate and sorry if my question not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay I just go to [GemBox Convert](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/SampleExplorer/Spreadsheet/CommonUses/Convert) I try upload my excel file, then convert into csv file, and the result is same as my convert file. So the problem is not coming from my script but in GemBox.Spreadsheet library. Thank you for your participate guys!

Answer (score 0):

Use the hex escape `\x22` such as:

```
Console.WriteLine ("\x22Literally\x22");
```

Outputs `"Litterally"`

Comment: sorry still not work. I know it's should real value I get from excel, after save to csv the string write with double quote three times.